# How to display Scanner inputted places in Java ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I want to search using village name and display all schools (both in the government and private classes) in that village. How do I do that?

```
class SchoolsMain {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    SchoolsAll[] schoolsLimit = new SchoolsAll[30];

    ArrayList<Government> govSchools = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Private> priSchools = new ArrayList<>();  


if (bandCat==4) {
            Government schools1 = new Government();    

System.out.println("Provide name of village ");
            String _Street = input.nextLine();
            schools1.setStreet(_Street);
            govSchools.add(schools1);



 if (bandCat==5) {
            Private schools2 = new Private();    

System.out.println("Provide name of village");
            String _Street = input.nextLine();
            schools2.setStreet(_Street);
            priSchools.add(schools2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Save all the schools to the corresponding village in a `List<String> village1`.

Then print them using a **stream** like :

`village1.stream().forEach(System.out::print);`

Comment: Thanks for the insight. However, the schools are inputted by the "user" using Scanner input, so, how am I supposed to save them to the corresponding village?

Comment: give an eye here :   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61693015/string-array-list-using-scanner